# Does Jenkins support docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins

I read in certain docker plugins, such as [docker-slave-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Slaves+Plugin), it shows there is support for compose but I do not understand how to implement it.

Has anyone used docker-compose in the Jenkins pipeline and how?

Comment: edited to hopefully fix what the downvote was for

Comment: why not use sh 'docker-compose ...' ? just make sure the docker-compose installed on the slave you are running

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using CoreOs and that does not have support for jenkins slave, there is no java and other things etc.  the plugins use the remote API i understand so they don't need to have the coreos configured as a jenkins slave.

Comment: So the jobs  running on the master ?

Comment: I was expecting that the jenkinsfile would orchestrate the commands in it(eg. git checkout, scripts, etc) from the master onto the coreos host in the docker container... is that not how this plugin works?.. or does it need to have the ability to connect to CoreOs in the same way it connects to traditional slaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer appears to be no.  It does not directly support compose.

I got around this by using the `script{}` blocks in the Jenkinsfile to manually call `docker-compose up` which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I installed docker and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose) on the Jenkins machine and run it with
  `sh 'docker-compose up'`
it is not a Jenkins plugin but it works.

Comment: When/where do you call sh 'docker-compose up' ?