# CI testing with docker-compose on Jenkins with Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

- I have tests that I run locally using a `docker-compose` environment.
- **I would like to implement these tests as part of our CI using Jenkins with Kubernetes on Google Cloud** (following [this setup](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial)).
- [I have been unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50197692/1561176) because [docker-in-docker does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31381323/1561176).

It seems that right now there is no solution for this use-case. I have found other questions *related* to this issue; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37214628/1561176), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48995717/1561176).

I am looking for solutions that will let me run `docker-compose`. I have found [solutions for running `docker`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35830359/1561176), but not for running `docker-compose`.

I am hoping someone else has had this use-case and found a solution.

---

**Edit:** Let me clarify my use-case:

1. When I detect a valid trigger (ie: push to repo) I need to start a new job.
2. I need to setup an environment with multiple dockers/instances (docker-compose).
3. The instances on this environment need access to code from git (mount volumes/create new images with the data).
4. I need to run tests in this environment.
5. I need to then retrieve results from these instances (JUnit test results for Jenkins to parse).

***The problems I am having are with 2, and 3.***

For 2 there is a problem running this in parallel (more than one job) since the docker context is shared (docker-in-docker issues). If this is running on more than one node then i get clashes because of shared resources (ports for example). *my workaround is to only limit it to one running instance and queue the rest (not ideal for CI)*

For 3 there is a problem mounting volumes since the docker context is shared (docker-in-docker issues). I can not mount the code that I checkout in the job because it is not present on the host that is responsible for running the docker instances that I trigger. *my workaround is to build a new image from my template and just copy the code into the new image and then use that for the test (this works, but means I need to use docker cp tricks to get data back out, which is also not ideal)*

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to use the pure Kubernetes resources to run tests directly by Kubernetes, not by `docker-compose`.

You can convert your docker-compose files into Kubernetes resources using `kompose` [utility](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tools/kompose/user-guide/).

Probably, you will need some adaptation of the conversion result, or maybe you should manually convert your docker-compose objects into Kubernetes objects. Possibly, you can just use [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) with multiple containers instead of a combination of deployments + services.

Anyway, I definitely recommend you to use Kubernetes abstractions instead of running tools like `docker-compose` inside Kubernetes.

Moreover, you still will be able to run tests locally using Minikube to spawn the small all-in-one cluster right on your PC.

Comment: Thank you Anton, I have found a successful workaround to use docker-compose as I wanted. However it does not scale (I eliminated my need to mount volumes by creating new docker images as part of the CI that already included the data i wanted to mount by using ADD) But now the problem is that they all run in the same context (docker-in-docker issues again) So I have been looking at using Kubernetes-only solution. but it seems that is also not fully established, Do you have some links that you can show how to do roughly what I am attempting?

Comment: You can check [that](https://medium.com/@TheJBStart/running-your-e2e-tests-in-kubernetes-engine-d10cc03a7d7e) article for example. That guy uses Jobs for run e2e test in Kubernetes.

Comment: Thank you for that link, it might prove useful, but it's not exactly what I am looking for, it is not using Kubernetes on Jenkins, which is what I need.

Comment: You can call Kubernetes from Jenkins without the plugin, just directly by `kubectl` or using Kubernetes API. So, those are 2 different things - spawning workers and spawning jobs right inside the cluster. Moreover, you can spawn Jobs even your Jenkins are not connected to the cluster.